# How to remember the selected text in content-editable and apply styles from the input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable, execcommand

lets say I have a div with content-editable = true. Now i want to color selected/highlighted text inside that div. I am using  document.execCommand("foreColor", false, color) where color is the input value. I want to let the user to edit the input.
Now the problem here is as soon as i start editing, focus from the selected/highlighted text gets removed.
I dont want focus to be removed whenever the input is changed.